# Is Fiddler AutoResponder compatible with SOAP apis?

Tags: fiddler

When I drag an existing call to **Autoresponder** it generates a rule **based on the method and URL**. This works fine for REST APIs but not for APIs that are not based on the URL(like SOAP). **Is there a way to make it respond based on the request body?**

I'll explain the full use case. I have a .saz containing about 100 POST request to a SOAP API containing a repro for a bug in a application that I've created. I'm looking for an easy way to replay the communication that causes my app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler to respond with soap but because the URLs are the same for different calls, only one can be set up to respond at a time.  After generating the rule create a .dat file that contains the soap response.

Comment: What if i only want to override one specific response? I do not want to change the response of all of the Soap calls.

Comment: @BlondCode you will have to create a new rule for each call and associate the correct response file.